# Use Dryscrape to login to Facebook

Tags: python, facebook

I'm trying to use Drcscrape to login to Facebook but I get this error.

I'm using OSX

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 420, in __init__
    self._port = int(re.search(b"port: (\d+)", output).group(1))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebook_scraper.py", line 40, in <module>
    sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url = 'https://www.facebook.com')
  File "/Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dryscrape/session.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.driver = driver or DefaultDriver()
  File "/Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dryscrape/driver/webkit.py", line 30, in __init__
    super(Driver, self).__init__(**kw)
  File "/Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 230, in __init__
    self.conn = connection or ServerConnection()
  File "/Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 507, in __init__
    self._sock = (server or get_default_server()).connect()
  File "/Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 450, in get_default_server
    _default_server = Server()
  File "/Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/webkit_server.py", line 427, in __init__
    raise WebkitServerError("webkit-server failed to start. Output:\n" + err)
webkit_server.WebkitServerError: webkit-server failed to start. Output:
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/./libQtWebKit.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/noppanit/.virtualenvs/envpy3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/webkit_server
  Reason: image not found
```

This is the snippet code.

```
import dryscrape

# make sure you have xvfb installed
dryscrape.start_xvfb()

# set up a web scraping session
sess = dryscrape.Session(base_url = 'https://www.facebook.com')

# we don't need images
sess.set_attribute('auto_load_images', False)

# visit homepage and search for a term
sess.visit('/')
q = sess.at_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
q.set('email')
q = sess.at_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
q.set("password")
login_button = sess.at_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_x"]')
login_button.click()

# save a screenshot of the web page
sess.render('facebook.png')
print("Screenshot written to 'facebook.png'")
```

Comment: I don't think facebook is open to such automatized logins. This is not just an email and pass (also a submit button), but maybe a csrf token and more. They have an api for authentication and some other actions - if that kind of processing and etc. would be possible (or is allowed), why they provide such api?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this (the second exception re: dyld) in the end? I'm encountering the same, even after uninstalling dryscape, installing qt, then re-installing dryscape.

Comment: What does your facebook.png show?
I think the xpath of the login_button is different in different cases. A more definite xpath would be //*[@id="loginbutton"]/input

Answer (score 0):

Try with input name it is working perfectly because id changed every time when page refreshing